# "Hacker" Type movie from the 80s/90s

Tags: identify-this-movie

I'm looking for a hacker type movie, sort of similar to real genius. In it the protagonists are your typical group of whiz kids that invent some crazy revolutionary computer that eventually gets stolen by the 'big bad corporation.' The group of kids then band together to invent an even better one with a floating keyboard. The kids break into the corporation's meeting and shows them the new and better computer.

Comment: This makes me think of " The first $20 Million is always the hardest. But it was released in 2002 instead of the 90's so I am not sure if this is the right movie.

Comment: Was it American? Where did you see it? Do you remember any actors or specific dialogue?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Sounds like [The First $20 Million Is Always the Hardest](http://www.imdb.com/title/tt0280674/)

> Andy, a successful marketing guy quits his job, because he feels disconnected with the values about work he learned from his father. He gets a new job at a top notch research facility, where he quickly makes a powerful enemy who makes him volunteer for a nearly impossible project: The $99 Personal Computer. He recruits the only available guys at the lab, three sociopaths. Together they really compile a revolutionary PC for $99, but then they become the victims of a venture capitalist and Andy's old foe from the research lab. Can he and his new friends find a way to overcome the problems?

Comment: BTW I deleted my answer earlier since someone beat me to it by a few seconds, but now that answer is somehow gone!